# Automapper Many to Many Mapping Including Joining Table Data

Tags: asp.net-web-api, entity-framework-core, automapper

I am developing an ASP.Net Core Web API using EF Core Code First (C#) and SQL Server.

I have a fairly simple scenario which I just cannot figure out. I have a `Form` entity and a `Site` entity. Each Form can have many Sites and each Site can be in many Forms. To enable this I have a `SiteForm` joining table. For each Site associated with a Form there is a `Leaving Date` field. So my `SiteForm` class looks like this:

```
    public class SiteForm
    {
        public Guid SiteId { get; set; }
        public Site Site{ get; set; }

        public Guid FormId { get; set; }
        public Form Form{ get; set; }

        public DateTime? LeavingDate { get; set; }
    }
```

My Form's Data Transfer Object (`FormDto`) is as follows:

```
    public class FormDto
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        ...
        public ICollection<LinkedSiteDto> LinkedSites { get; set; }
            = new List<LinkedSiteDto>();

    }
```

And my `LinkedSiteDto` is like this:

```
    public class LinkedSiteDto
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }

        public string Ident { get; set; }

        public DateTime? LeavingDate { get; set; }
    }
```

Having populated the database I can get the Sites for each Form using the following mapping:

```
    CreateMap<Form, FormDto>()
        .ForMember(dto => dto.LinkedSites, opt => opt.MapFrom(
                form => form.SiteForms.Select(sf => sf.Site).ToList()));
```

I just cannot figure out how I would include the `LeavingDate` value from each joining table entry? Any suggestions would be very gratefully received.

Comment: Remove `Select(...).ToList()` from the mapping and create and configure map from  `SiteForm` to `LinkedSiteDto`.

Comment: Brilliant, You're a star, thanks.